# WPF Indent Multiple Groupings in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid with multiple groupings embedded within each other. I want to do 2 things:

1. Indent each embedded grouping
2. Have an expander for the initial grouping, but not for any embedded ones

Is this possible with wpf?

UPDATE:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupDescription}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander>
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" Items"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Everything is possible in WPF. [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Short Answer: Yes.  What exactly do you have a question on?

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering how to implement both of these things in my xaml? Example code perhaps? I'll update my question with the part of my xaml that implements the expander